# Mysql - How to update a column using another column's value plus some strings

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following column & value:

ColA = "8765"
ColB = "2137"

I would like to update ColB in the same table to the following value:

ColC = "[8765][2137]"

How can I do it using phpmyadmin (meaning just sql syntax)?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET ColC = CONCAT("[", ColA, "][", ColB, "]");
```

Answer (score 15):

```
UPDATE
    myTable
SET
    ColC = CONCAT('[', ColA, '][', ColB, ']')
--WHERE...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use only this one!
**I've tested on the live server.**

```
UPDATE table SET column_name = CONCAT( Column_A, ' ', Column_A );
```

In between single quotes will add a space. 
You can remove that if it is not required.